# custom meta box data not saved

Tags: metabox, gallery

After two day of reasearch and questions without answer, today someone has suggested me a way to add a custom metabox field to the wordpress images. My scope is to add an url when the image are uploaded or modified and for now I'm only able to display the input field where user can add the url, but the input will not be saved and I'm unable to get it back on the front-end.

I want to use this custom metabox function with the `get_post_gallery()` that will output the urls of the images I've added inside a gallery, but I don't know how to combine this, and I need to fix the saving of the inserted url.
Can anyone help me or guide trought the implementation?

```
<?php
 function add_image_link()
 {
   add_meta_box(
     'image_link_box',
     'Link image to url',
     'image_link_field',
     'attachment'
   ); 
 }
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_attachment', 'add_image_link' );

 function image_link_field( $post )
 {
   ?>
   <label for="image-link">Link URL</label>
   <input type="text" name="image_link" id="image-link" class="postbox">
   <?php
 }

 function save_image_link( $post_id )
 {
   if( array_key_exists( 'image_link', $_POST ) ){
     update_post_meta(
       $post_id,
       'image_link_url',
       $_POST['image_link']
     );
   }

 }
 add_action( 'save_post_attachment', 'save_image_link' );
?>
```

Comment: I think the meta/input does get saved, but you should use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) in your `<input>`.

Comment: I've looked to the table, but there is no trace of the key. Also I need toimplement nonces. I've tried with `get_post_meta()` but the supposed values are not loaded.

Comment: Have a look at my answer and regarding the nonces, see [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually, for posts of the type `attachment`, you should use the [`edit_attachment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_attachment/) (action) hook and not `save_post_attachment`:

```php
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'save_image_link' );        // use edit_attachment
//add_action( 'save_post_attachment', 'save_image_link' ); // not save_post_attachment
```

Secondly, your meta box is not currently displaying the meta value, so you should display the value in the input field, and you can use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to retrieve the meta value:

```php
<input type="text" name="image_link" id="image-link" class="postbox" value="<?php // wrapped
    echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_link_url', true ) ); ?>">
```

PS: You should always sanitize/escape user-supplied and untrusted data; e.g. above I use [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) to escape the value, and you can use [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field) to sanitize the submitted value: `sanitize_text_field( $_POST['image_link'] )`.

#### Sample Implementation *Using `get_post_gallery()`* (for the `[gallery]` shortcode)

This is based on the [example here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery/#comment-642). And as I've mentioned before, you can use `get_post_meta()` to retrieve the custom field's value (which in your case is an URL address).

```php
// Get the gallery data (attachment IDs and URLs).
$gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
if ( $gallery ) {
    foreach ( wp_parse_id_list( $gallery['ids'] ) as $i => $att_id ) {
        // Get the custom link URL.
        $url = get_post_meta( $att_id, 'image_link_url', true );

        // Display the image. You can add other attributes later..
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '"><img src="' . // wrapped
            esc_url( $gallery['src'][ $i ] ). '" alt=""></a> ';
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

#### A Better (Non-Metabox) Solution

*If* you want to be able to edit the custom field via the [Attachment Details dialog](https://wordpress.org/support/article/media-library-screen/#attachment-details), then you should just forget about using the meta box and instead try the following:

1. This part adds the custom field to the dialog:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', function ( $form_fields, $post ) {
       $form_fields['image_link'] = array(
           'label' => 'Link to image URL',
           'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_link_url', true ),
       );

       return $form_fields;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```
2. This part saves the field as a meta data:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', function ( $post, $attachment ) {
       if ( isset( $attachment['image_link'] ) ) {
           $meta_input = isset( $post['meta_input'] ) ?
               (array) $post['meta_input'] : [];

           $meta_input['image_link_url'] = $attachment['image_link'];

           $post['meta_input'] = $meta_input;
       }

       return $post;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```

Note that `image_link` is the form field (`input`) name, whereas `image_link_url` is the meta key.

And this solution also *works well with the standard "Edit Media" page* — from the Attachment Details dialog, you can get to that page by clicking on the "Edit more details" link.

*Full code I used for testing [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/e5a9b9d97e73810bacf947d819f46fc5#file-non-metabox-option-php).*

Comment: It's an url field, and i need to retrive the value on some post/pages where attached post images are used inside an `<a>` tag.

Comment: Answer updated. Let me know! :)

Comment: I will try and let you know, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I have updated the question, the data I will add are not saved. I'm still unable to display the images of the gallery with the related links.

Comment: Ok, look, if you change the `add_action( 'save_post_attachment', 'save_image_link' )` to `add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'save_image_link' )`, the custom field should get saved. And if use the `get_post_meta()` in the `<input>`, then the field value would be displayed in the `input`. You also asked for a sample implementation using the `get_post_gallery` function which works for the *standard `[gallery]` shortcode*, and I've given you a the sample. So referring to the original code, what's your current code now, and have you tried the sample implementation?

Comment: Yes, I've implemented your code suggestions for the metabox and changed the wrong hook into the suggested one, but the field after the saving, will remain empty. To display It I'm using the class function I've posted into the question update, but it's working wrong and will display all the madia library images instead of the images attached to the related post or page. Also The `get_post_meta()` will not load nothing. I will give another try, for now I need to fix the gallery according to the oop plugin code

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer and I hope the meta is saving properly now - but if not, there's a simpler solution which works also with the [Attachment Details dialog](https://wordpress.org/support/article/media-library-screen/#attachment-details). Also, I edited the question (rolled back to previous revision) since you've asked another question specific to that plugin code..

Comment: Can the metabox be added also to the attachment details dialog?

Comment: No, but the custom field, can. And I'd use the non-metabox option..

Comment: ok, I saw the updated answer.  thanks for the help. I will work on my plugin code to add the custom field and the metabox feature. It will be helpful for me if you can link some references to the available wordpress screens for metaboxes and custom fields

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you a definitive list on that. But the most common can be referenced [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/#user-contributed-notes). And can we end the discussion here? If you've got further questions, you can either post another question or search on WPSE, SO, Google, etc...