# Display attached images of a page or post that are insetred using gallery

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development

I've finally added a custom metabox to link some images to some custom urls, (thanks to the Sally CJ for the help in troubleshooting my previous issue with [adding a metabox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/351867/custom-meta-box-data-not-saved)), I need now to adapt this plugin code that will add a swiper slider using a custom shortcode. I've noticed that It will load all the media library images and I don't want this, I want to display only the gallery images that are attached to the post or page where the shortcode is used. 
I've tried in past with `get_post_gallery_images()` but it will not work, so I've used the `WP_Query` that is causing this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php 
public function imageSlider( array $attr ) : string
  {

    ob_start();

    extract(shortcode_atts(
      array(
        'class' => null,
        'id' => null
      ), $attr)
    );

    $this->args = [
      'post_status'    => 'inherit',
      'post_type'      => 'attachment',
      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ];

    $this->images = new WP_Query( $this->args );

    $this->img = [];
    $this->link = [];
    foreach( $this->images->posts as $image ){
      $this->link[] = get_post_meta($image->ID, 'image_link_url', true);
      $this->img[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
    }
    ?>
      <div class="swiper-container <?php echo $class; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <?php
            foreach( $this->img as $i => $src ){
          ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->link[$i]; ?>">
              <img class="swiper-slide img-fluid w-100" src="<?php echo $src; ?>">
            </a>
          <?php
            }
          ?>
        </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Actually, why not just create your own custom shortcode using [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)? Or use the standard `[gallery]` shortcode? Or the Gallery block in the block editor. But looking at the code, you can try adding `'post_parent' => get_the_ID()` to the WP query args (`$this->args`). That would give you the attachments attached to the current post/page.

Comment: It's part of a custom plugin for shortcodes, I've posted only the code that I need to fix. I will try your suggestion.